# Access SQL Query absurd result

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to update a column in access table and operation I need to perform is multiply all the numbers in the column by 1000. After performing operation, I am getting absurd results as few cells get updated and multiplied whereas other cells become zero.

I have a table in access on which I am performing operation on one of its column. Column contains integer value and I want to multiply each entry in column by 1000. Total number of rows in database is around 20000. I am using below query.

```
UPDATE Table_Static SET Table_Static.NAV = Table_Static.NAV * 1000
```

Out of 20000 rows, few gets updated correctly and others become 0 after operation, although there were values in those cell before operation. There is an observation that NAV rows later in the table are not getting updated. Please suggest whether Access has such issues ? Also, suggest corrective measure. This update query is part of many queries that I am running.

Thanks

```
UPDATE Table_Static SET Table_Static.NAV = Table_Static.NAV * 1000
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You should at least include the table schema (data types), this might very well be an issue with numbers stored as strings.

Comment: *Column contains integer value* - if it's really `Integer`, they have a number range of –32768 to 32767, and you won't get very far with multiplying by 1000.

Comment: Thanks Andre...It helped me. Erik, thanks for your input. I will keep your suggestion in mind in my future questions.